# Tabbed terminal emulator that has "Save state" functionality

Tags: terminal, terminal-emulator

Is there a terminal emulator that will have tabs and once closed and reopened (maybe with some identifier specified on the command line interface) will:

- open the same amount of tabs
- name each tab exactly as before
- have them ordered as before they were closed
- have them `cd` in the same directories
- set the same env vars
- run the same executables that were running in the same tabs

?

Optionally it should "save state" into an external file.

Comment: `iTerm` does (some of) this on macOS, but you don't mention what Unix you're running.

Comment: But the affected computer will, for example, be rebooted in the interim, right? (I guess I'm asking if you're aware of screen/tmux/[byobu](https://byobu.org/) which do a subst of what you're asking?)

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz yes, thanks for pointing this out, should work across reboots (that's the point actually). I just need to open a dozen of tabs each time I start working and run servers, utilities etc. Used to have a script that would do that for xfce4-terminal, but it was a pain to edit and some changes were required quite often.